# Problem with exporting an open lid box with red color inside and white color outside to use in Adobe Stager

Tags: objects, export

I have made a simple box with open lid with red inside and white outside. everything looks good in Blender and export with "write material" selected. But when i import it into Adobe Stager its just an object and no colour. I am pretty new in Blender and cannot figure out where the problem is? Please help.
Also how can I make a box in Blender that I can change the colours in adobe stager? I really appreciate for the help.

Comment: This is on the edge of not being about blender. There is a chance that the export is not working as intended, but otherwise I would vote to close this. Adobe Stager might not support the material system Blender exports with, and adapting to a 3PS is not really the scope of this site. Also, you didn’t even mention the file type you are using. Collada, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have exported with both FBX and OBJ. FBX, I selected copy and embed texture. In OBJ it writes the MTL file which is the same as all the objects Adobe Stager use. I was thinking to make a UV map but this is just a simple base color. I have seen videos they import Blender object into Adobe Painter which is the same system as Stager and they can put color on the object. Do you have any recommendation ? Thank you,